# Crash when compiling: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, widget

I am getting this exception I searched on stackoverflow but the solutions I found didn't work for me.

**I faced this error:**

```
Unhandled exception:
Crash when compiling:
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1

#0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:264:36)
#1      Class._computeOnClause (package:kernel/ast.dart:1156:73)
#2      Class.onClause (package:kernel/ast.dart:1139:49)
#3      SourceClassBuilder.checkMixinApplication (package:front_end/src/fasta/source/source_class_builder.dart:908:52)
#4      SourceLoader.checkMixins (package:front_end/src/fasta/source/source_loader.dart:2714:19)
#5      KernelTarget.buildOutlines.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/kernel/kernel_target.dart:532:14)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      withCrashReporting (package:front_end/src/fasta/crash.dart:133:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      KernelTarget.buildOutlines (package:front_end/src/fasta/kernel/kernel_target.dart:404:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      IncrementalCompiler.computeDelta.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/incremental_compiler.dart:408:33)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      IncrementalCompiler.compile (package:vm/incremental_compiler.dart:75:50)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:604:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     listenAndCompile.<anonymous closure> (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:1316:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.
```

**Here are my pages:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5N8mr.png

```
class stream extends StatefulWidget {
  stream({super.key});

  @override
  State<stream> createState() => _streamState();
}

class _streamState extends State<stream> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<User?>(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
      builder: (context, userSnapshot) {
        if (userSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
        }

        final User? currentUser = userSnapshot.data;

        return StreamBuilder<List<Task>>(
          stream: FirestoreDataSource().streamTasks(currentUser?.uid ?? ''),
          builder: (context, tasksSnapshot) {
            if (tasksSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(strokeWidth: 0.9),
              );
            }

            final List<Task> tasksList = tasksSnapshot.data ?? [];

            if (tasksList.isEmpty) {
              return const Center(
                child: Text(
                  'No tasks available.',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: textColor),
                ),
              );
            }

            return ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: tasksList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final task = tasksList[index];
                return Dismissible(
                  key: UniqueKey(),
                  onDismissed: ((direction) {
                    FirestoreDataSource().deleteTask(task.id);
                  }),
                  child: Task_wdgts(task),
                );
              },
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Don't worry if there is some unused code, it's a work in progress and this error just stopped me from continuing what I was doing.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqrM6.png

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  bool show = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: whatsapp(),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: stream(),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Do you have any idea about the solution?

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Can you confirm that `tasksSnapshot.data` returns non-empty data?